# How to use authentication options in MongoDBStore class

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The NODE-JS app wants to store the session data in a database. My problem is I can not set the DATABASE authentication option(userName, password)

**syntax is **

```
const MongoDBStore = require("connect-mongodb-session")(session);
const store = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: "mongodb://localhost:27017",
  databaseName: "rbacDB",
  collection: "sessions",
  expires: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2,
});
```

In the above class **MongoDBStore**, I need to set the options **user: "xxxx" and pass: "231456"**

Comment: Try `mongodb://USER:PASS@localhost:27017/DB?authSource=admin`

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood by looking at github code
The library that you have linked internally simply calls official mongodb library connect method with uri that you have passed

https://github.com/mongodb-js/connect-mongodb-session/blob/master/index.js#L76

That means you should be able to pass the actual connection string in uri and it should work

```
"mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/exampledatabase"
```

That is,

```
const MongoDBStore = require("connect-mongodb-session")(session);
const store = new MongoDBStore({
uri: "mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017",
  databaseName: "rbacDB",
  collection: "sessions",
  expires: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2,
});
```

Comment: Yes, It works with URI having the user name and password, but I don't want to put this information in URI. Is there any option or scope to set authentication information without URI?

Comment: I don't see an issue in specifying it in mongo uri, that's actually a standard, the other way is to call db.authenticate function, but the issue with that approach is the library that you are using, it's not exposing mongo object outside, the only way would be to fork and create authenticate function inside of the lib instead of doing what they are doing on Line 76 as linked above.
Although still in that case you'd need to pass username and password as function arguments.

I don't think there is any reason you would go by that way.